# Bufferedreaded ready method losing data

Tags: java, bufferedreader

The following method doesn't capture the data sometimes. I believe it is because of the .ready() function.

We have hacked our way through it by doing a sleep, but I don't think it's full proof and seems like a bad hack.

Can you make suggestions on how to fix this method so it works when the request is fully read?

Thanks in advance

```
/**
     * Parses a client request and calls the appropriate handler
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private void processClientRequest() throws Exception{
            Socket connectedClient = null;
        BufferedReader clientRequest = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectedClient.getInputStream()));

        System.out.println(clientRequest);
        String requestString = clientRequest.readLine();

        String header = requestString;

        //Break up request
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(header);

        //Different request parts
        String httpMethod = tokenizer.nextToken();
        String httpQueryString = tokenizer.nextToken();

        //Print client request
        StringBuffer responseBuffer = new StringBuffer();

        //Sleep to bypass weird clientRequest.ready() error
        if (httpMethod.equals("POST")) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }

        while (clientRequest.ready()) {
            responseBuffer.append(requestString + " ");
            System.out.println(requestString);

            requestString = clientRequest.readLine();
        }

        //Process GET request
        if (httpMethod.equals("GET")) {
            processGETRequests(httpQueryString, requestString);


        }else if (httpMethod.equals("POST")) {
            processPOSTRequests(responseBuffer, httpQueryString);
        }
    }
```

Comment: To start, you shouldn't be using `StringTokenizer` in modern code, and there's no reason to be using `ready()`

Comment: You seem to to be writing your own http server. What exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: I am all about optimizing. Any suggesting Brian?

Comment: David, I am trying to write an http server :)   It's already working fine for APIs... just this one bug

Comment: Don't do that. Use Embedded jetty, or use the lightweight http server included in the jdk. Again. DO NOT WRITE YOUR OWN http server unless you just want to learn and you won't use it in production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you work with strings you have to always agree on encoding and never use defaults. In your

```
// use wathever charset encoding you know is pressent on the socket stream like UTF-8
new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "US-ASCII")
```

You don't need to call the ready method, the method readLine() will block untill there is a new line to be read. Your while should be

```
while ((requestString = clientRequest.readLine()) != null) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: That is why you should not try to build your own http server :) You can use the one that comes with the oracle jvm http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/LightweightHTTPServer.htm